# What is the difference between t.belongs_to and t.references in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

What is the difference between `t.references` and `t.belongs_to`?
Why are we having those two different words? It seems to me they do the same thing?
Tried some Google search, but find no explanation.

```
class CreateFoos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :foos do |t|
      t.references :bar
      t.belongs_to :baz
      # The two above seems to give similar results
      t.belongs_to :fooable, :polymorphic => true
      # I have not tried polymorphic with t.references
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: They do work the same -- is that such a bad thing?  references inserts a foreign key column for you.  You could use belongs_to instead to make your migration more readable. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html for some details.

Comment: Not saying it is a bad thing. Just got confused about if they do work the same or in different ways, since I can find no documentation specificaly saying they work the same. [http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html) is also not clear on that matter.

Comment: This is likely just for backward compatibility and `references` will be deprecated and removed in a future release of rails. Don't take my word on this, it's just an educated guess.

Comment: "The other helper is called references (also available as belongs_to). In its simplest form it just adds some readability" -- from the guide

Comment: Also here's the source code -- belongs_to is a straight alias of references https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/88aa2efd692619e87eee88dfc48d608bea9bcdb4/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb#L421

Comment: @muffinista: Your source code link is perfekt. Please place an answer so I can mark it as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 197, accepted):

Looking at [the source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/88aa2efd692619e87eee88dfc48d608bea9bcdb4/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb#L421), they do the same exact thing -- `belongs_to` is an alias of `reference`:

```
  def references(*args)
    options = args.extract_options!
    polymorphic = options.delete(:polymorphic)
    args.each do |col|
      column("#{col}_id", :integer, options)
      column("#{col}_type", :string, polymorphic.is_a?(Hash) ? polymorphic : options) unless polymorphic.nil?
    end
  end
  alias :belongs_to :references
```

This is just a way of making your code more readable -- it's nice to be able to put `belongs_to` in your migrations when appropriate, and stick to `references` for other sorts of associations.

Comment: I wonder if they are going to keep it like this in the future or they are going to remove one of them!? I like it this way, being able to choose whichever makes my code look more like real english.

Comment: I would guess that both are here to stay.  Looking at the commit logs, it's been this way since 2007.

Comment: IMO, `references` is an ambiguous choice for a term. They renamed `before_filter` to `before_action`, which was a good move because it reduced ambiguity. One advantage of `references` is that it's simply different from what you use in the model, so you get less confused if you're in the model or migration. But any term that differs would satisfy this criteria.

Comment: IMO `references` is better term in db-level.

Comment: I don't really think they actually mean the same thing in English... So it's a bit weird.