# t.references in the migration vs belongs_to in the model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I was reading the Rails Guides and I found these lines of code:

```
  class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
     def change
       create_table :comments do |t|
          t.string :commenter
          t.text :body
          t.references :post

          t.timestamps
       end

       add_index :comments, :post_id
     end
 end
```

I also read Michael Hartl's book, Rails Tutorial and I did not find anything about the "t.references" used in the code above.
What does it do? In Michael's book I used has_many and belongs_to relations in the model and nothing in the migrations(not event t.belongs_to).

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788188/what-is-the-difference-between-t-belongs-to-and-t-references-in-rails

Comment: @sameers not really, the other one is asking about the `belongs_to` in the migrations not in the models

Answer (score 33):

This is a fairly recent addition to Rails, so it may not be covered in the book you mention. You can read about it in [the migration section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#creating-a-standalone-migration) of Rails Guides.

When you generate using, say,

```
rails generate model Thing name post:references
```

... the migration will create the foreign key field for you, as well as create the index. That's what `t.references` does.

You could have written

```
rails generate model Thing name post_id:integer:index
```

and gotten the same end result.

Comment: But is it still acceptable to add a foreign key the old way?( by using  belongs_to IN THE MODEL)

Comment: That's adding a foreign key to the model, not to the underlying database. You'll need to do that anyway. If you generate your model using `post:references`, though, the generator will add `belongs_to :post` for you automatically.

Comment: Incidentally, you can actually use `belongs_to` in the migration - it's an alias of `references`

Comment: No, the book had been updated since this feature was added, but Michael felt references was too much magic, and teaches each element separately. Personally I think it's a mistake not to at least mention this shortcut once the basic concepts have been taught, as db relationships are core to building pretty much any Rails app, so it's something done repeatedly.

Comment: In the question above, is the defined `post_id` index superfluous here?

Answer (score 8):

See [this section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#special-helpers) of Rails Guides.

In your case, `t.references` creates a `post_id` column in your `comments` table. That means that Comment belongs to Post, so in `Comment` model you have to add `belongs_to :post` and in Post model: `has_many :comments`.

Comment: Funny, but the section does not actually mention the exact method `t.references` at all.