# How To add new table and link it with previous table in with adding index in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dependencies

I have this table structure:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :username 
      t.string :email
      t.string :encrypted_password 
      t.string :salt
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

And I want to add a new table as shown below:

```
class CreateHolidays < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :holidays do |t|
      t.string :earn_leave
      t.string :seek_leave
      t.string :unplanned_leave
      t.timestamps
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index(users,id)
  end
end
```

What should I do for this, please also suggest commands that can/should be used for migration.

Answer (score 0):

You want to look up about [`foreign_keys`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key):

```
#app/models/holiday.rb
class Holiday < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end

#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :holidays
end
```

This will mean you have to [add the `user_id` foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16309742/t-references-in-the-migration-vs-belongs-to-in-the-model) to your `holidays` data table:

```
class CreateHolidays < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :holidays do |t|
      t.references :user 
      t.string :earn_leave
      t.string :seek_leave
      t.string :unplanned_leave
      t.timestamps
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

You must remember that Rails is designed to be built on top of a [relational database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database). As such, it uses `foreign_keys` in the tables to [locate associated records](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association):

[image]

The above will allow you to call:

```
@user.holidays
```

and

```
@holiday.user
```